# How to evaluate the integral: $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \cos(x)\sqrt{\cos(x)} \,dx$

Tags: integration, elliptic-integrals

$$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \cos(x)\sqrt{\cos(x)} \,dx$$
I've been trying to find a way to integrate this function for a while.
From my research I think this should reduce to an elliptic integral but I can't seem to find a way to reduce it to one of the three canonical forms.

I found this [article](https://planetmath.org/ReductionOfEllipticIntegralsToStandardForm) which might be useful. I've tried to follow some of the steps but I think it's out of my sphere of knowledge at the moment.
So contributions, even if very little, are much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the easiest way to solve it is by noticing that we can rewrite $\sqrt{\cos x} $ as $ \cos^{\frac12}x$. Thus we have to find $$I=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \cos ^{\frac32}x \mathrm dx $$ Now what about using [Beta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BetaFunction.html)? For $m, n > -1$:$$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \sin ^mx \cos ^nx \mathrm dx =\frac12 B \left(\frac{m+1}{2}, \frac{n+1}{2} \right) $$ Now just set $m=0$ and $n=\frac32$.  $$I=\frac12B\left(\frac12, \frac54\right)$$ Now using some useful identities such as the relation with the gamma function $$B(x, y) =\frac{\Gamma(x) \Gamma(y)} {\Gamma(x+y)} $$ and that $\Gamma(1+x)=x\Gamma(x)$, $\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)=\sqrt{\pi} $ gives that $$I=\frac12 \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)\Gamma\left(\frac54 \right)} {\Gamma\left(\frac74 \right)} =\frac12\frac{\sqrt{\pi} \frac14\Gamma\left(\frac1
4 \right)}{\frac34\Gamma\left(\frac34\right)}$$ Additionally one can use gamma reflection formula here if it's desired.

Comment: Don't worry, finished it myself.
Wow, this is so much better. Thank you!

Comment: Great job! I started writing it so I updated it.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed it is an elliptic integral:
$$ I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left(\cos x\right)^{3/2}\,dx\stackrel{x\to \pi/2-x}{=}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left(\sin x\right)^{3/2}\,dx\stackrel{x\mapsto \arcsin u}{=}\int_{0}^{1}u^{3/2}(1-u^2)^{-1/2}\,du$$
can be written as $2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{u^4}{\sqrt{1-u^4}}\,du $ or as
$$ \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}v^{1/4}(1-v)^{-1/2}\,dv = \tfrac{1}{2}\,B(5/4,1/2)=\frac{\Gamma\left(\tfrac{5}{4}\right)\Gamma\left(\tfrac{1}{2}\right)}{2\,\Gamma\left(\tfrac{7}{4}\right)}=\frac{\Gamma\left(\tfrac{1}{4}\right)^2}{6\sqrt{2\pi}} $$
due to the properties of the Beta and Gamma functions. On the other hand it also equals
$$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1-\tfrac{1}{2}\cos^2\theta}} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}\,K\left(\tfrac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{\pi}{3\,\text{AGM}\left(1,\sqrt{2}\right)}$$
according to Mathematica's notation for the elliptic modulus and the relation between $K$ and the arithmetic-geometric mean. This tour gives a nice relation between a trigonometric integral, a special value for the $\Gamma$ function, a complete elliptic integral of the first kind, the $\text{AGM}$ mean and two  hypergeometric series:

> $$ 6I=\frac{\Gamma\left(\tfrac{1}{4}\right)^2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}=2\sqrt{2}\,K\left(\tfrac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{2\pi}{\text{AGM}(1,\sqrt{2})} = \frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{2}}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}^2}{32^n}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{6\binom{2n}{n}}{(4n+5)4^n}.$$
>   This incredible chain of identities led me to ponder the inclusion of the [lemniscate constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LemniscateConstant.html) among the "classical" mathematical constants.

Comment: This makes so much sense!
This is part of a bigger integral involving the lemniscate. If interested:
$$\frac83 a^3 \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\pi/2}\ cos(2\phi) sin(\theta) \sqrt{cos(2\phi)}$$

Comment: I was wondering... Shouldn't there be $\frac12$ in front of $B(5/4,1/2)$ ?

Comment: @RobertAdrian: you're right, I hope everything is fixed now.

Comment: +1 for including lemniscate constant in the list of classical mathematical constants. On the other hand the relation between Gamma values at rational arguments and values of elliptic integrals for singular moduli runs deep (as [Chowla and Selberg tell us](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN243919689_0227&DMDID=DMDLOG_0008)).

Answer (score 2):

Others have shown you certain evaluations which involve the $\beta$ function, but I'll show you how this general formula is derived. 
$$I(a,b)=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^a(t)\cos^b(t)dt$$
$$u=\sin^2(t)\implies du=2\sin(t)\cos(t)dt\\\implies dt=\frac1{2}u^{-1/2}(1-u)^{-1/2}du$$
I'm sure you can work out the change of the bounds by yourself
$$\therefore I(a,b)=\frac1{2}\int_0^1u^{a/2}(1-u)^{b/2}u^{-1/2}(1-u)^{-1/2}du$$
$$\therefore I(a,b)=\frac1{2}\int_0^1u^{(a-1)/2}(1-u)^{(b-1)/2}du$$
$$\therefore I(a,b)=\frac1{2}\int_0^1u^{(a+1)/2-1}(1-u)^{(b+1)/2-1}du$$
And now we recall that $$\beta(a,b)=\int_0^1 t^{a-1}(1-t)^{b-1}dt$$
Which gives 
$$I(a,b)=\frac1{2}\beta\bigg(\frac{a+1}2,\frac{b+1}2\bigg)$$
Furthermore, we know that $$\beta(a,b)=\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}$$
Which of course gives our integral:
$$I(a,b)=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{a+1}2)\Gamma(\frac{b+1}2)}{2\Gamma(\frac{a+b}{2}+1)}$$
Plug in your values for $a,b$, and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Very interesting. I've encountered the Beta function in the past when I was studying probability, but I never thought I'd see it in an integral like this one. Thank you for your contribution!

Comment: @RobertAdrian You're very welcome. After I learned this trick, the Beta function started popping up everywhere!